# howTo translate Web2Py SQL Code with ROW_NUM, LIMIT into DAL?

Tags: sqlite, web2py, data-access-layer

How is this (SQLite Code), working:

```
csv_rt_bat_c_x = db.executesql('select * from csv_rt_bat_c LIMIT 100')
```

converted into Web2Py DAL?

Thats working:

```
csv_rt_bat_c_x = db().select(db.csv_rt_bat_c.ALL)
```

But how to add the 100 LIMIT (to speed it up for development) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`limitby`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#orderby-groupby-limitby-distinct-having-orderby_on_limitby-join-left-cache) argument:

```
csv_rt_bat_c_x = db().select(db.csv_rt_bat_c.ALL, limitby=(0, 100))
```

Comment: As workaround I found: csv_rt_bat_c_x = db.executesql('select * from csv_rt_bat_c LIMIT 100')  Yours is much better. It allows to speed up when testing on large tables and is acroding to the standard.